# convert char A[] to double

Tags: c, arduino-ide

I have an arduino code that inputs volume in a char datatype, I want to convert it to double, Ive tried using atof but it wont work. Whats the problem from my code. Sorry Newbie here!!

```
double v;
int data_count = 0;
int i;
char Data[16];
char volume[16];
char inputTime[16];

// Define the Keymap for Keypad
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'.', '0', '#', 'D'}
};
lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Input Volume:");

  if (customKey != NO_KEY && customKey != '#'
      && customKey != 'A' && customKey != 'B' && customKey != 'C'
      && customKey != 'D') {
    Data[data_count] = customKey;
    lcd.setCursor(data_count, 1);
    lcd.print(Data[data_count]);
    data_count++;
  }

  if (customKey == '#') {
    volumelength = data_count;
    for (i = 0; i < volumelength; i++) {
      volume[i] = Data[i];          
    }
    clearData();
    nextstate();
    data_count = 0;
    v = atof(volume);
  }
```

Comment: Using floating point numbers on a sluggish 8-bit microcontroller without FPU is always the terribly wrong thing to do. Don't do that - it is not a PC. There's nothing in your program that justifies the use of floating point.

Comment: You are defining arrays of char _pointers_, not arrays of char. Are you sure you don't want to rethink that?

Comment: okay mybad, Ive tried using these:
    char Data[16];
    char volume[16];
    char inputTime[16];
and still cant convert the volume[] array to double. I want to convert it to use it for calculation.

Comment: In addition to what @Mark said, you are not allocating or specifying any space for the arrays. My advice is to study arrays and pointers before trying to code C or you will run into many frustrations.

Comment: If you use `char volume[16]`, try calling `printf("%s", volume);` before the conversion to make sure that your buffer does in fact represent a numeric value, and is null-terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in arduino language there is `toFloat()` ( https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/tofloat/ )

else `atof()` should work as it in the *avr-gcc* `stdlib.h` library for 8-bit AVR CPU like on arduino

( https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html ) :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char s[] = "11.248"
double f = 0;

f=atof(s);
```

also see **http://www.ethernut.de/nutwiki/index.php/Converting_Strings_to_Floating_Point_Values** ( ethernut is for 8 bit CPUs )

possibly check if the content of `Data` is really a float ...

another `atof` example in avr-gcc / arduino : https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=98595.0

Comment: One more thing for this to work is to cast it as double. 
`f=(double)atof(s);`